# Maven Dependencies references non existing library jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar

Tags: hibernate, maven, pom.xml

I have a problem regarding maven. In my current eclipse project I used maven for dependecy management and it worked fine until now.

The project is not working anymore and it states that:

> The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\RSone.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\transaction\jboss-transaction api_1.1_spec\1.0.1.Final\jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar'

I tried maven clean and maven update which did not work. The line in my pom.xml is marked red and states:

> Missing artifact org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.1.Final pom.xml /GestionVirment
>
> Missing artifact org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.1.Final   pom.xml /GestionVirment

This is the content of my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.rsone.virement</groupId>
    <artifactId>GestionVirment</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>GestionVirment Maven Webapp</name>
    
    <developers>
        <developer>
            <id>rsone</id>
            <name>roussi abdelghani</name>
            <email>roussi.abdelghani@gmail.com</email>
        </developer>
    </developers>

    <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
        <spring-version>3.2.8.RELEASE</spring-version>
        <spring-security-version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring-security-version>
        <hibernate-version>4.2.11.Final</hibernate-version>
        <mysql-version>5.1.30</mysql-version>
        <spring-security>3.2.5.RELEASE</spring-security>
        <apache-connection-pooling-version>1.4</apache-connection-pooling-version>
        <slf4j-version>1.7.6</slf4j-version>
    </properties>
    

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        

        <!-- Apache's Database Connection Pooling -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>${apache-connection-pooling-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>${apache-connection-pooling-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Spring Security Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- logging, slf4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency> 
        
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>GestionVirment</finalName>
                <plugins>
    
                <plugin>
                
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                        <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
    
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                        <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                        <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
    
            </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

- I'm using **Tomcat** and not jboss

This is the block that caused this problem :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
     <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Tomcat vs. JBoss. I copy-pasted your `pom.xml` and ran `mvn dependency:resolve`. Works flawlessly. Does `C:\Users\RSone\.m2\settings.xml` define non-standard Maven remote repositories which don't have the artifacts you're missing?

Comment: there is no settings.xml file under .m2 , there is just the folder repository

Comment: What about `$M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml`? What happens if you run `mvn dependency:resolve` in the project folder?

Comment: @AbelRoussi If you solved your question can you write an answer or delete it?

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni , I have just create a new maven project , and copy/past my code and then it works fine