# Adding Quartz dependency, all dependencies missing

Tags: quartz-scheduler

When the Quartz dependencies has been added to my project, the Problems window is complaining that all dependencies of my project are missing.

**Quartz dependency**

```
    <!-- Quartz --> 
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz-jobs</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

After removing the Quartz dependencies, the project works fine.It seems to me that some repositories are not available.

Answer (score 0):

It was due to the specific settings of my company in the `settings.xml` in the C:\Users\Erwin\.m2 folder.
After creating a default settings file: settings-private.xml with de default template from [apache/maven](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/master/apache-maven/src/conf/settings.xml)

This question pointed me in the right direction: [Maven Dependencies references non existing library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27734936/maven-dependencies-references-non-existing-library-jboss-transaction-api-1-1-spe)